# Resolve template argument to its ordinal index

Tags: c++, templates

The title describes the core of my question, though the actual problem is hard to describe.

Essentially, I need to create a class that behaves like std::tuple which also allows the user to access its members by type instead of index (assuming type uniqueness is guaranteed), but I do not want the class itself to be templated, i.e. only the constructor is.

For example, if my class was named "Foo", I would like to do the following,

```
Foo foo { &A, &B, &C };  // where A, B, C are of unique types
```

And then be able to retrieve the pointers via:

```
foo.Get<TypeA>(); // should return &A
foo.Get<TypeB>(); // should return &B
```

And keep the class declaration for Foo without templates.

Comment: For what reason are you avoiding a templated type? You can do this without, but it will probably require extra storage and/or runtime (though perhaps less code-size). If we know the full extent of the constraints we can probably come up with a better solution :-)

Comment: When Foo has too many elements, having templated declaration becomes messy. Especially since it gets passed around multiple functions.

Comment: C++14's [`std::get(std::tuple)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) can return elements by type.

Comment: yes, but std::tuple<> has to be declared with all the types it will hold, if passed around it becomes messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way this is going to work with `Foo` as a class is RTTI. Something along these lines:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <typeindex>

class Foo {
public:
  template<typename... Args>
  Foo(Args*... args) {
    // bit hackish here, but this way we can use pack expansion
    // to populate the map.
    void *foo[] = {
      (data_[std::type_index(typeid(Args))] = static_cast<void*>(args))...
    };
  };

  template<typename T> T *GetData() const {
    auto iter = data_.find(std::type_index(typeid(T)));

    if(iter == data_.end()) {
      return nullptr;
    }

    return static_cast<T*>(iter->second);
  }

private:
  typedef std::map<std::type_index, void*> storage;
  storage data_;
};

int main() {
  std::string s = "foobar";
  int i = 2;
  double d = 3.0;

  Foo f(&i, &d, &s);

  std::cout << *f.GetData<int        >() << "\n"
            << *f.GetData<double     >() << "\n"
            << *f.GetData<std::string>() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Not if `Foo` is to be a class. `std::tuple` is a class template.

Comment: Not a bad idea, though personally I'd go with a dummy `template <typename... Args> void dummy(Types && ...) { }` as the hack (`dummy((data_[x] = args)...)`). But I guess that's a matter of taste.

Comment: Yes that would work, though at the cost of having to keep a map and perform the lookup.  I was hoping to avoid that, but it may be impossible.